# Selection in R (using Char)

Tags: r

```
choose = letters(1:4)
f = function(x,y,choose){
    if(choose == 'a'){
        total = x + y
    }
    else if(choose == 'b'){
        total = x - y
    }
    else if(choose == 'c'){
        total = x * y
    }
    else{
        total = x / y
    }
    print(total)
}
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong with this code???
I'm still new at this Language

Comment: What is `letters(1:4)`supposed to do? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your function works for me, but your indexing is wrong: try `choose = letters[1:4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the first line but this is what I think you wanted

```
    f = function(x,y,choose){
  if(choose == 'a'){
    total = x + y
  }
  else if(choose == 'b'){
    total = x - y
  }
  else if(choose == 'c'){
    total = x * y
  }
  else{
    total = x / y
  } 
  return(total)
}

the_value<- f(5,5,"a")
print(the_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to generate a sequence of letters this is how you do it

```
letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )]

choose = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )]
f = function(x,y,choose){
  if(choose == 'a'){
    total = x + y
  }
  else if(choose == 'b'){
    total = x - y
  }
  else if(choose == 'c'){
    total = x * y
  }
  else{
    total = x / y
  } 
  return(total)
}
print(f(5,5,choose[3]))
```